# Spring MVC - POST to different url from controller

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I am trying to build a chatbot. I can receive data from the user input from javascript via ajax, but I want to send a response after the POST is triggered (the response for now can just be the user input).

For example : 
javascript

```
           //...create jsonObj using userinput
           //Post text to Spring MVC via ajax
            $.ajax({
                url: "myurl/chat",
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify(jsonObj)
            });
```

Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/chat", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")
public void inputChat(@RequestBody String userInput) {
    //I want to send a response back to javascript here
}
```

Then back in javascript I want to listen for the response and parse it. All the examples I've found use $getJSON which does the request upon user prompt, not listen for the response. Also in my case **I want to send data from Spring MVC to javascript without a GET request from javascript.**

How can I go about doing this?

Edit : in javascript I would be using something like :

```
$.post('/chat/response', function (data) {
   // data is an object
}, 'json');
```

How can I do a POST from the Spring MVC Controller?

Comment: Maybe you should be using a websocket solution?

Comment: @ScaryWombat That definitely sounds like a better idea. I'll try that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using a **websocket** would be a better solution. If you want to response a json string for the `POST` request of `myurl/chat`, you just need to change the method like below code.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/chat", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")
@ResponseBody
public Map<String,Object> inputChat(@RequestBody String userInput) {
    //I want to send a response back to javascript here
    Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    result.put("response", "hello!");
    return  result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add @ResponseBody to your method.
Its helps spring to understand that the method have to send back the response to that ajax call when the POST request return some value.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/chat", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
  consumes="application/json")
 @ResponseBody
 public void inputChat(@RequestBody String userInput) {
//I want to send a response back to javascript here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple you can use below code to get response in javascript from Spring MVC controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/chat", 
method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
public @ResponseBody String inputChat(@RequestBody String userInput)
        throws ParseException, IOException {
    String statusValue = "0";
    String messageToSend = "{\"status\":\"" + statusValue + "\"}";
    String json = new Gson().toJson(messageToSend);
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    return json;
}
```

In "statusValue" you can give your response.

Following is ajax code to get value.

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/chat',
         data: JSON.stringify(jsonObj),
         success: function(response){
             var message = JSON.parse(response);
             // in message you get statusValue  from MVC controller.
         },
         error: function(xhr, status, error) {
         }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple you can do this use below code in javascript to Spring MVC controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/chat", 
method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
public @ResponseBody String inputChat(@RequestBody String userInput)
        throws ParseException, IOException {
    String json = new Gson().toJson("Your string");
    return json;
}
```

Ajax code.

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/chat',
         data: JSON.stringify(jsonObj),
         success: function(response){
             // do anything with this response.
         },
  });
```